# record addition in sql

Tags: sql

I am making an inventory management system.
I wanted to enter products which were bought by the customer in product_sale table.

```
create table product_sale(
recipt# int primary key identity(1001,1),
product_id int,
product_name varchar(50),
brand_name varchar(50),
prchase_date date,
purchase_time time,
gross_price int,
discount_price int,
retail_price int,
quantity int,
)
```

the problem is that one customer can buy several items, and they will be inserted in multiple rows but as **recipt#** is primary key,so the other record will be added on another  **recipt#**
so what should I do either should remove primary key contraint from **recipt#**
or something more preferred....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--Product info--
CREATE TABLE PRODUCT
(
PRODUCTID INT NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_PK PRIMARY KEY(PRODUCT_ID)
);

--sales info--
CREATE TABLE SALES
(
RECIPT_ID SMALLINT DEFAULT (0) NOT NULL,
PRODUCTID INT DEFAULT (0) NULL,
CONSTRAINT SALES_PK PRIMARY KEY(RECIPT_ID),
CONSTRAINT SALES_PRODUCT_FK FOREIGN KEY(PRODUCTID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(PRODUCT_NAME)
);
```

Edit[1]: since you elaborated more, I would always want to have two different tables because you want a list of your inventory on one table then on the second table you would want the sales. This helps keep all the clutter away from the view you wish to seek.

Comment: Actually I have three tables in db.
1) product purchased table
2) stock table
3) sale table


I don't want to add customer details because during sale  we don't consider customer name or id.
What I want to do is to just add a record of products purchased by a customer and it will absolutely be on an id ,so I am using recipt#.

In the end I have to create a report by jasper report.

Comment: @mohammadharis Since the new information you provided that you do not want to keep track of the customers this is how I would do it. This is because I want my store inventory separated away from my sales. This is because if I ever need to check the stock or check what I might want to remove from the inventory of the store, I do not want to see all the information about the product if I am checking through what was the least popular.

Answer (score 0):

Mu suggestion is you should denormalize this table by separating order item and receipt ID. Think this is classic example and you can find lots of examples in web.

For example http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php